# Python 3, tkinter, how do I display a list of strings, one by one, under each other

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have a list of strings.

Something like this

```
Answers=["House - Maja","Boat - Paat","Plane - Lennuk"] etc.
```

I want to display them in a tkinter window, the list lenght is not a constant. I can't do it with "listbox", because I also want to add buttons there.

**EDIT:**
I got it!

```
label = ttk.Label(root, text="\n".join(map(str, yourlist)))
```

Comment: I'd recommend using a Canvas if you need to include other widgets. It also supports the scrollable interface so you can have both horizontal and vertical scrolling for your long list of answers.

Comment: I don't understand your comment about buttons. You can no more add buttons to a listbox than you can a label widget. Why is a multi-line, non-scrollable label better than a multi-line, scrollable listbox?

Comment: @Strukks by the way: you have list of strings so you don't need `map(str,)` => `text="\n".join(list_of_strings)`

Comment: @Bryan Oakley, you can't add buttons to a listbox window? Atleast I couldn't, but you can put buttons to a window with labels. I might be wrong, but I didn't get it to work that way.

Comment: @Strukks: you can add buttons in the same window as a listbox or label, but you can't add buttons inside a listbox that is attached to each item in the listbox. And while you can technically put a button inside a label, there's no advantage to doing so.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley: I guess it's my bad then, I tried putting buttons into a listbox window but somehow I didn't get it to work.